# relation "django_content_type" already exists django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

oke, I have a django application. And I tried to update the models. So I did a

makemigrations and migrate. But that didn't worked. So I truncated the table django_migrations.

And I did a python manage.py makemigrations:

```
Migrations for 'zijnAdmin':
  zijnAdmin\migrations\0001_initial.py
    - Create model Category
    - Create model Animal
```

but when I try now: python manage.py migrate. I get this errors:

```
Running migrations:
  Applying contenttypes.0001_initial...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\repos\DWL_backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 87, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "django_content_type" already exists
```

But I see that changes have been made in the tables. and the app works fine. But I still get this warning when I do a :  python manage.py runserver 192.168.1.135:8000

```
You have 25 unapplied migration(s). Your project may not work properly until you apply the migrations for app(s): accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions.
Run 'python manage.py migrate' to apply them.
July 24, 2023 - 15:49:58
Django version 4.2.3, using settings 'zijn.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://192.168.1.135:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.
```

Question: how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
psycopg2.errors.DuplicateTable: relation "django_content_type" already exists
```

this error means that "contenttypes" app is trying to crate a table that already exists in data base.

before you do anything backup you database so you don't lose your data if anything goes wrong, then check the status of your migrations to see if there is any migrations that are not applied:

```
python manage.py showmigrations
```

make sure migrations are applied by running  `python manage.py migrate`
if you see any errors during the migration resolve them
after running the migrate command check the status of migrations again using  `showmigrations` command to make sure  all migrations have been applied

if you have manually truncate the django-migrations table it must have led to some inconsistencies  to resolve this issue you can try clearing the migrations for the "zijnAdmin" app and then create the initial migration again:

```
python manage.py migrate zijnAdmin zero
python manage.py makemigrations zijnAdmin 
python manage.py migrate
```

and since you truncate the django-migrations table it is possible that the django_content_type table was partially created to make sure that "contenttypes" app's migration runs fine you can try recreating the "django_content_type" table using this:

```
python manage.py migrate contenttypes --fake
```

the --fake flag tells the django to mark the migration as applied without actually running it

if these didn't work it's good idea to check the migration files, the state of your database and check any changes you made to the models

these are the things that came to my mind.

I hope this helps you.

Comment: @Kiarash.whowh. Thank you. I just went though all the options: Apply all migrations: WelzijnAd, accounts, admin, auth, authtoken, contenttypes, sessions with python manage.py migrate contenttypes --fake for each option. And now it works again like a charm. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have truncated the migrations table, Django will now try to run all the migrations from start. This also includes few Django library's own migrations for creating the user, auth, content_types tables, etc. But since those tables are already present, you are getting the error and the migrations is not able to complete.

The easiest way to fix this would be to DROP the entire database and start a new blank one.

You can take backups of every table other than `django_content_type` and `django_migrations`
And in your new Database you can restore it. So migrations and content_type will be added when you run `python manage.py migrate` command and the rest of the tables you can import from your backup.

Comment: @Arun.Thank you for your suggestion. But in this case it was not necessary to drop the whole database.